# Print the name and home directory path associated with a username

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to ask for a username and print the name and home directory path associated with that username

```
echo Please enter your username
read username
```

I am not sure how to use $username to locate information regarding its home directory and name.

Comment: What if Eve enters her name as Alice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo Please enter a username
read username

cat /etc/passwd | grep "$username" | cut -d ":" -f6
cat /etc/passwd | grep "$username" | cut -d ":" -f5
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk -F: -v v="$username" '{if ($1==v) print $6}' /etc/passwd`

Without awk:

`cat /etc/passwd | grep "$username" | cut -d ":" -f6`

User name:

`cat /etc/passwd | grep "$username" | cut -d ":" -f5`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know that abbreviation. OP?

Comment: Original Poster.  The person asking posing the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember. Thanks :) I added how to display name.

Answer (score 1):

use [`getent`](http://man.cx/getent)

```
read -p "username: " username
IFS=: read username password uid gid gecos homedir shell < <(getent passwd "$username")
echo "fullname=${gecos%%,*}"
echo "homedir=$homedir"
```